# Calculating the convergence radius of a Taylor expansion

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the radius of convergence for the Taylor series $$\left(\cot\dfrac{\pi}{100}z\right)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n}\left(z-20\pi\right)^{n}$$

The singularities of this function are the $100n$ where $n$ are integers(roots of $\dfrac {\pi}{100}z=n\pi$ ) Among these singularities, the  one that is closest to $20\pi$ is 100,so the radius is $100-20\pi$.

Is my proof valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use that the convergence radius of the Laurent expansion (in general, in a punctured neighborhood) is the distance to the first singularity, then yes, your proof is correct.